# Dimensions when developing for smart watches

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, dimensions, sony-smartwatch

Hi I am doing research into developing for smart watches for an upcoming project i may be undertaking. I am looking to develop a custom launcher for a smart watch to be used as the main interface that the user interacts with. I have done my research into this and i think i know what direction to head in. What I dont know how ever (and Im sure a lot of others dont and would like to know) is how to set my self up in Eclipse or Android Studio to develop apps for the small screen sizes of Smart watches.

Is it simply setting dimensions in the res/values folder or is it more complicated than that? Also is there any special SDKs i can get my hands on to aid me in developing for Smartwatches?(i know of the Sony SDK but havnt been able to find any others.)
Also is there a way to configure my IDEs so that i can easily set up Smart watch projects?

Comment: Wondering why the downvotes? Is it because its an opinion question or is it because OP didnt show his work

Comment: I was wondering the same thing Smart watches are such a new technology that there isn't any central SDK or IDE for them so i was hoping to get the advice and wisdom of those who may have already developed for smartwatches cause i have not before.

Comment: is there a generic dimension that i could use when initially testing the Launcher app I plan on developing?

Comment: What do you mean by SmartWatch?  Something running native Android you can run native code on? e.g. OMate, WereIt and a number of others.  Or are you talking something working as a companion to a smartphone with the main app on the smartphone and then some SDK to access the watch like the Sony watches.

Comment: Something that will be running full native android, but it will be working as a companion as well if it doesn't have a SIM card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an emulator to see your results for different dpi.

DPI is a measure that you can use on your dimens.xml, and if you have a measure in pixel,you can use this to know which kind of dpi is.

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        System.out.println("low");
        // ...
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        System.out.println("medium");
        // ...
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        System.out.println("high");
        // ...
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        System.out.println("xhigh");
        // ...
        break;
    }
```

For example, Nexus 4 has a density of 320 (xhdpi), Samsung Galaxy SII 240 (hdpi)

Comment: So i can use this to set the dimensions of my app or to atleast get the dimensions to ensure it fits onto a smartwatch screen?

Comment: I want to be able to set in the IDE the dimensions of the app so that i can test it on the smartwatch i can developer the UI for it.

Comment: in this way you can be sure that all of watches will have same dimension, and then to do debug to adjust these.. (with an emulator maybe..)

Comment: Okay thanks where would i put this in my activity?

Comment: this should go into onCreate()

Comment: can you flag my answer??

Comment: Turns out this is actually easier than i thought it would be i was making a mountain out of a mole hill as it where. Thanks!